# Android Google Map how to check if user is in marker rectangle region

Tags: java, android, google-maps, distance, area

I am using Google Maps, and want to be able to detect if a user is in the rectangle of a Marker (placed on a map), using the user's current location. I have the user's current location coordinates (latitude and longitude) and the marker's coordinates but do not know how to calculate whether the user is in the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to use the `PolyUtil.containsLocation` using the rectangle corner points (centered on the marker) and the user's location:

```
boolean isWithin = PolyUtil.containsLocation(userPt, rectanglePts, true);
```

Here is docs on [map utils](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/).  And the PolyUtil [java docs](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html)

Here is a code fragment demonstrating.  Note the rectangle rotation is handled by the utility so it need not be aligned to the coordinate system.  In fact it doesn't even need to be a rectangle.

(I chose to use circles for display purposes but can be replaced with markers.):

In this example, the marker is drawn as a circle in green, the containing rectangle and two arbitrary points (possible user locations) to show result of calculation (RED=in, BLUE=out).

```
// Create rectangle coordinates 
LatLng upperLeft = new LatLng(39.274659,-77.639552);
LatLng upperRight = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(upperLeft, 12000, 120);
LatLng lowerRight = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(upperRight, 5000, 210);
LatLng lowerLeft = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(lowerRight, 12000, 300);

// Make a list for the polygon
List<LatLng> polygonPts = new ArrayList<>();
    polygonPts.add(upperLeft);
    polygonPts.add(upperRight);
    polygonPts.add(lowerRight);
    polygonPts.add(lowerLeft);

// Draw rectangle
mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().addAll(polygonPts).geodesic(true).strokeColor(Color.BLACK));

// Draw marker (center of rectangle)
LatLng mPos = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(upperLeft,6000,120),2500, 210);

// Now add a circle to represent the marker - circles display nicer
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(mPos).fillColor(Color.GREEN).radius(300).strokeWidth(1));


// Add two points and compute whether they are inside or outside rectangle and
// set color based on that (RED=inside BLUE=outside)
LatLng circleInside = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(mPos,1000, 320);
LatLng circleOutside = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(mPos,4000, 45);

// Determine if point is inside rectangle and set color accordingly.
int insideCircleColor = (PolyUtil.containsLocation(circleInside, polygonPts, true) ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE);
int outsideCircleColor = (PolyUtil.containsLocation(circleOutside, polygonPts, true) ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE);

// Add to map
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(circleInside,1000, 320)).fillColor(insideCircleColor).radius(200).strokeWidth(1));
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(circleOutside,1000, 320)).fillColor(outsideCircleColor).radius(200).strokeWidth(1));

// and zoom to center
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mPos, 12.0f));
```

And display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the box, the longitude and latitude will be between the bounding box's points. Check this site for how exactly the longitude and latitude work.
https://gsp.humboldt.edu/olm/Lessons/GIS/01%20SphericalCoordinates/Latitude_and_Longitude.html